# Browsers ignoring protocol in canonical links?

Tags: html, http, https, canonical-link

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com">
    </head>
</html>
```

See this code: canonical href is absolute, page is static and protocol is explicitly declared.

However, if i navigate to `https://www.example.com` and inspect the page code, i see that browser (tried with chrome and firefox) rewrite that href to be `https://www.example.com`.

Why so?

My actual issue is with sharing tools, which i'd want to ignore protocol while fetching share statistics.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a Cloudflare setting (which i didnt even mention in my question) was overriding all links in pages, so this issue has nothing to do with browsers.

Switching off the Cloudflare "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites" setting solved this.